# Error opening pages with python

Tags: python

I am trying to open websites in python. Lets cut to the chase.

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('http://google.com')
```

(my code)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\webbrowser.py", line 1, in <module>
    import webbrowser
  File "C:\Python27\webbrowser.py", line 3, in <module>
    webbrowser.open('http://google.com')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open'
PS C:\Users\ug>
```

(my error)

What did I do wrong?

Comment: rename your file named `webbrowser.py` to something else.

Comment: Same error. I don't think the name is the problem sadly.

Comment: did you clear the pyc files too ?

Comment: just ran your code from the terminal and it worked. I think karthikr is correct. your file must cause a naming conflict.

Comment: Yeah. Is there something else I need to import?

Comment: @GertrudeSpangleHeart, delete the `.pyc` file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import webbrowser       

alink = 'http://eample.com'
new = 2
webbrowser.open(alink, new=new)
```

If this doesn't work, run this and post the output: `dir(webbrowser)`

webbrowser.py is the same name as the import module. Try renaming the file to wbrowser.py and see if this helps.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'webbrowser' is not defined

Answer (score 2):

To summarize and clarify the comments:

1. Rename `C:\Python27\webbrowser.py` to `webbrowser_test.py`
2. Delete `C:\Python27\webbrowser.pyc` and `C:\Python27\webbrowser.pyo`
3. Run `python webbrowser_test.py` and you should get the desired results.